# How to display google map in reactjs inside of page height and width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  trying to put a google map on a after some description on page to start in a react project, and am having trouble. I have created google map in another component and calling that googlemap  component into main component.

Map is loading correctly, but facing issue with border map is getting out of the section. I have attached image too. I think the problem is with page  component height

```
const Con = () => {


    return (
        <div className="Contact">
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs lg="8">
                        <h1><strong>Contact Us</strong></h1>
                        <br></br>
                        <div>
                        <h5><strong>For any enquiry, please contact Andrew Lal Ji at lalnco@yahoo.co.uk</strong></h5>

                        <p><strong>Coming by Car: </strong></p>
                        <p>Please use post code G3 7LH for Sat Nav.</p>

                        <p><strong>Coming by Bus:</strong></p>

                        <br></br>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                        < MapWrapper />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Now i used con.js in App.js module

Here is my component google_map.js:

```
const mapStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '400px'
  }

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={15}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 55.866701, lng: -4.279272}}
        >

        <Marker position={{ lat: 55.866701, lng: -4.279272}} />

      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("mykey")
})(MapContainer)
```

Comment: change height:'400px' with minHeight:'400px' and check the result :)

Comment: nothing changes  @Imran Rafiq Rather

Comment: I am checking. Give me a moment please... What I feel is your <Col> within the container class has a height of 400px or fixed value.  That is why the overflow is happening, Check that in your console and try to debug in console.

Comment: Want to know about the <Col> within your <Row>... You have  <Col xs lg="8"> , and in the image that you have shared, there is some more data on the right side of this <Col>. If there exists a <Col xs="4"> Check the height of that Col...

Comment: If you can put the code on CodeSand box and share the link, or put your code on github and share the link. I will debug it for you :) I fell it's the height issue either with some Row or Col and that's why it is overflowing .Otherwise I have to start a new react project to debug your code :)

Comment: if i place inside another row still the same issue @ Imran Rafiq Rather with <Col xs lg="12">

Comment: Just give me a moment. See bro, we debug code by going into developer console (Ctrl+Shift+I) and try to see which height is fixed... I am trying to do it for you.. Once I debug it, I will let you Know :) Try till then

Comment: hey @Imran Rafiq Rather https://react-ab43pz.stackblitz.io/ my structure look like this

Comment: Let me see if I can figure out the bug

Comment: Bro the stackblitz link react-ab43pz.stackblitz.io is not opening :)

Comment: hey @Imran Rafiq Rather checkout this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ab43pz

Comment: Sure, let me see

Comment: I figured where the Issue is. The MapContainer component has on a div implement within the google maps library a  position: absolute value. That's why it is coming out of the flow. Let  me see how to  update the CSS and you life will get easier :)

Comment: but if this is the problem with div within the google maps library how can we override it? Is it possible

Comment: yes it is using our CSS class selector and selecting children div with trick... I have done these things a lot at work

Comment: I am figuring out in the developer console once done, I will show you how it is done..

Comment: Thanks a lot bro , i am a begineer in React just started few days back can share some useful resource and content

Comment: That's perfectly fine... I am here to help . I will try my best...

Comment: hey Bro, Congratulations! Your Problem is solved :)

Comment: hey @ Imran Rafiq Rather bro what's the solution?

Comment: have posted my answer, just check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was coming due to the default CSS set by the Map library. Mostly because of **`position:absolute;`** property

I have used my own custom class and updated the CSS.

**Note:** I have used Styled-Jsx to quickly use my CSS. You can use the same CSS in a seperate CSS file and import it here. Or do **`npm install --save styled-jsx`**

Here are the code changes in your LetChangeMap.js file (MapContainer) component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
 

const mapStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '400px',
  }

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
      <Map google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={15}
        className="mapContainerWrapper"
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 55.866701, lng: -4.279272}}
        >
 
        <Marker className="mapContainerMarker" position={{ lat: 55.866701, lng: -4.279272}} />

    <style jsx>{`
        .mapContainerWrapper{
          position:relative !important;
        }

        .mapContainerWrapper div:first-child{
          position:relative !important;
        }
    `}</style>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
 
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("key")
})(MapContainer)
```

StackBlitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-library-issue

StackBlitz Output: https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-library-issue

Comment: hi @Imran Rafiq Rather what if i dont want to use npm install --save styled-jsx can i run still?

Comment: Yes of course, You create a seperate CSS file, Use the same CSS that I have shown and then import it in your project. eg,. import './mapStyles.css'

Comment: Its working fine thanks a lot bro @Imran Rafiq Rather but again one issue now map looking as previous one i update my question

Comment: What is the issue friend...Let me also share the StackBlitz links for you to play around...

Comment: the map is not displaying as the previous one bro

Comment: Let me figure it out ... It is also a CSS issue, width this time

Comment: I have to generate an API key from google, to actually see the map...Would you quickly guide me in doing so bro :)

Comment: hehe... I never said share the key. I said guide me to generate the key fast... By the way from which country you belong. I am from India and it's 2:03 am already. That's why I thought you could quickly get me through the steps to generate the API key

Comment: it a long process anyways i will look into it i am also from india thank you so much

Comment: I have just used a key, and checked it. We are able to drag on the map but initially it coming rendering only half of the div. let me try to solve it.. You also debug in console. By the way I have worked in IBM, Photon and GiveIndia... :)

Comment: Its working brother i just changed position from static to relative it working as expected anyways thankyou so much brother

Comment: Most Welcome :) Keep it up :) And Enjoy coding

Comment: Yai, it is working, Default behavior of postion is static, and relative also works :), in fact works fine in this case. Let me update the answer

Comment: By the way do you know what this error actually is Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared
    at prompt.js:1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211899/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-akhi21).

Comment: hi @Akhi21 Sure let me have a look into it. Will get back to you soon... These are the days of fasting...So, I am mostly away from stackoverflow... Still I will look into it when I get time :)

Comment: Hi @Akhi21 It seems the question has been removed :)